# why does it say : ''Failed to search : data not available'' when i try to search for a movie in 'videos'?

Tags: video, search

here is a preview of what is happening:

[image]

As you see i have searched for 'venom'. but it's not working. and to show you that the movie trailer is in fact available on 'apple movie trailers' in 'videos' look at the home page (look at the middle posters):

[image]

update for @cocomac:

[image: version]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @cocomac I'm on ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @cocomac see the update.

Comment: Instead of pasting pictures it would be great to add the information directly into your question using terminal commands and copying them. (e.g. version can be fetched in terminal by `cat /etc/lsb_release`)...

Comment: @kanehekili i still prefer pictures as i am not a tech person and i don't even know what you're saying. don't bother explaining.

Comment: `Videos` and `Apple Movie Trailers` are two different locations.  Do you have any videos in your `Videos` folder?  Or are you trying to get a global search to find what you are looking for regardless of what folder or location you are in?

Comment: @terrance when i open the app videos, i get videos that are on my computer and there is the tab named ''channels'' next to the tab named ''videos''. when i go to ''channels'' there's a channel named ''apple movie trailers'' there. i am trying to search for trailers that this channel is supposedly allowing me to search.

Comment: Nice that YOU like pictures but the people helping you do not.

Comment: @ it doesn't make sense how one could NOT like pictures. it's so easy and quick to explain stuff.